# Back button for iframes separately

Tags: javascript

My website contains 4 iframes. I am trying to create back button for each iframe separately is it possible to create separate button for iframe. please help me.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
myFrame1.history.back ();   // or
myFrame1.history.go (-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
<iframe name="frame1"></iframe>
```

For this IFrame, the JavaScript is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="frame1.history.back ();">Back IFrame 1</a>
```